# How to call a function from a script in an other script matlab

Tags: matlab

**Were given this scriptpoinfixe.m file that has this starting code :**

```
clear all; close all;

g = @(x) -0.25* (x^3 - 3*x^2  - 2);
x0=1.5;
epsilon=1e-7; N=100;

x(1)=x0;

x1=g(x0);

e_n=abs(x1-x0);
errel=e_n/abs(x1);

nbiterations=1;


while (errel>epsilon) & (nbiterations <N)
          x0=x1;
          x1=g(x0);
          e_n_1=e_n;
          e_n=abs(x1-x0);
          errel=e_n/abs(x1);
          nbiterations=nbiterations+1;
          x(nbiterations)=x1;
end
```

**we've been asked to create the function pointfixe.m by modifying scriptpointfixe.m and deleting things in it.
So right now i only tried to add the function like this :**

```
clear all; close all;


g = @(x) -0.25* (x^3 - 3*x^2  - 2);
x0=1.5;
epsilon=1e-7; N=100;

x(1)=x0;

%%% 1ère itération de la methode de pt fixe
x1=g(x0);

e_n=abs(x1-x0);
errel=e_n/abs(x1);
% initialiation du compteur
nbiterations=1;


function [x] = pointfixe(g, x0, N, errel)

while (errel>epsilon) & (nbiterations <N)
          x0=x1;
          x1=g(x0);
          e_n_1=e_n;
          e_n=abs(x1-x0);
          errel=e_n/abs(x1);
          nbiterations=nbiterations+1;
          x(nbiterations)=x1;
end
end
```

**Now were asked to create a matlab script that we name devoir.m which defines the values of x0,g1, N and e
so i created devoir.m :**

```
g = @(x) -0.25* (x^3 - 3*x^2  - 2);
x0=1.5;
epsilon=1e-7; N=100;


pointfixe(g, x0, N, epsilon);
```

**But when i run devoir.m i get this error : Unrecognized function or variable 'pointfixe'.**

This makes no sens for me since they are in the same folder, i don't understand why it's not found.
Thanks for your help.

[image]

**EDIT FOR COMMENT**

[image]

Comment: You can't call a script as a function. Make it into a function first

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for reply, so how do i transform the script : pointfixe.m into a function if it's initially a script? I guess i just create a complete new file which is a function and paste the code ? My teacher was not really clear as i can see.. Thanks

Comment: Probably best practice to put the function into its own .m file. After that name the file the same as your function name. Also, keep it in the same working directory.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 Thanks for reply, now that i created a new function why does it tell me : unable to define local function pointfixe because it has the same name as the file. As what you said that it has to be the same name, thanks. when i run it now it says : Local function name must be different from the script name.

Comment: @codetime Did you remove the other instances of pointfixe(). The only one should be in the new file, then it should work like a charm. I'll try it out now.

Comment: I tested it and the only errors I get pertain to using variables before declaring the in the function.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 Weird, look my setup on my last screenshot ( see edit in orginal post)

Comment: @codetime Try making a new folder and copy and create two files as I have in my answer. Here's a folder that I uploaded with the two files that might help. https://github.com/MichaelTr7/StackOverflow/tree/master/Tutorial%2040:%20Functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Steps for creating a function:

### Global Function [Scope Within Directory]:

• Create a .m file with the same name as the function.

• Have only one instance on this function within the newly created script.

### Local Function [Scope Within Script]:

• Create an instance of function within the main script.

• Function can be only called within the script it is declared in.

### File 1: devoir.m

```
g = @(x) -0.25* (x^3 - 3*x^2  - 2);
x0 = 1.5;
epsilon = 1e-7; 
N=100;

pointfixe(g, x0, N, epsilon);
```

### File 2: pointfixe.m

```
function [x] = pointfixe(g, x0, N, errel)

while (errel > epsilon) & (nbiterations <N)
          x0=x1;
          x1=g(x0);
          e_n_1=e_n;
          e_n=abs(x1-x0);
          errel=e_n/abs(x1);
          nbiterations=nbiterations+1;
          x(nbiterations)=x1;
end
end
```

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**

Comment: Ok nice it works (i think it's because i had : clear all; close all; not sure), thanks. Man coming from real programming language to matlab is kinda rough haha. Thanks again.